# How to perform auto.arima for all variables at once and correctly set the frequency parameter using R

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I have this dataset.

```
s=structure(list(date = c("01.10.2020", "06.10.2020", "11.10.2020", 
"16.10.2020", "21.10.2020", "31.10.2020", "05.11.2020", "10.11.2020", 
"20.11.2020", "30.11.2020", "05.12.2020", "10.12.2020", "19.12.2020", 
"20.12.2020", "24.12.2020", "25.12.2020", "03.01.2021", "04.01.2021", 
"08.01.2021", "13.01.2021", "18.01.2021", "23.01.2021", "28.01.2021", 
"29.01.2021", "02.02.2021", "07.02.2021", "17.02.2021", "18.02.2021", 
"22.02.2021", "23.02.2021", "27.02.2021", "28.02.2021", "04.03.2021", 
"05.03.2021", "09.03.2021", "10.03.2021", "14.03.2021"), red = c(1600L, 
1360L, 1520L, 1360L, 1528L, 1600L, 1634L, 1508L, 1380L, 1548L, 
1456L, 1460L, 1103L, 1732L, 1084L, 1080L, 1504L, 1008L, 1259L, 
1230L, 1393L, 1225L, 1482L, 1068L, 1386L, 1316L, 1400L, 784L, 
1418L, 580L, 1546L, 920L, 1540L, 578L, 1644L, 1016L, 1568L), 
    green = c(1392L, 1056L, 1248L, 1120L, 1160L, 1296L, 1426L, 
    1388L, 1172L, 1372L, 1352L, 1252L, 964L, 1524L, 940L, 936L, 
    1392L, 1008L, 1054L, 999L, 1244L, 964L, 1350L, 1092L, 1043L, 
    1044L, 1064L, 640L, 1045L, 660L, 1170L, 884L, 1148L, 602L, 
    1212L, 808L, 1176L), blue = c(960L, 712L, 816L, 784L, 664L, 
    960L, 1226L, 1204L, 932L, 1068L, 1200L, 1044L, 737L, 1292L, 
    668L, 728L, 864L, 832L, 838L, 672L, 1060L, 628L, 1166L, 860L, 
    678L, 772L, 792L, 272L, 639L, 420L, 802L, 644L, 756L, 362L, 
    844L, 408L, 776L), nir = c(3096L, 2696L, 2904L, 2680L, 2960L, 
    2392L, 2120L, 2020L, 2232L, 2088L, 1928L, 2072L, 2488L, 2488L, 
    2262L, 1912L, 2120L, 1928L, 2516L, 2504L, 2566L, 2414L, 2556L, 
    2296L, 2568L, 2621L, 2616L, 2472L, 2584L, 2696L, 2744L, 2792L, 
    2743L, 3000L, 2840L, 2568L, 2772L), swir = c(3040L, 3104L, 
    3040L, 3040L, 3232L, 2848L, 2656L, 2256L, 2656L, 2656L, 2464L, 
    2592L, 2976L, 2464L, 2885L, 2080L, 2720L, 2144L, 3216L, 3104L, 
    3104L, 3020L, 3120L, 2080L, 3104L, 3337L, 3488L, 2016L, 3232L, 
    1744L, 3603L, 2080L, 3552L, 1888L, 3808L, 2144L, 3614L), 
    B05 = c(2016L, 1696L, 1952L, 1824L, 1952L, 1888L, 1824L, 
    1712L, 1696L, 1760L, 1648L, 1696L, 1376L, 1952L, 1440L, 1376L, 
    1712L, 1376L, 1568L, 1504L, 1712L, 1554L, 1773L, 1424L, 1632L, 
    1632L, 1696L, 1184L, 1632L, 1056L, 1862L, 1296L, 1888L, 1056L, 
    2000L, 1376L, 1923L), B06 = c(2656L, 2272L, 2512L, 2400L, 
    2528L, 2208L, 2016L, 1872L, 1952L, 1952L, 1824L, 1888L, 1952L, 
    2160L, 1952L, 1696L, 1968L, 1888L, 2050L, 1952L, 2208L, 2062L, 
    2224L, 2016L, 2075L, 2081L, 2208L, 1952L, 2208L, 2096L, 2250L, 
    2272L, 2283L, 2208L, 2462L, 2144L, 2336L), B07 = c(2976L, 
    2528L, 2784L, 2528L, 2784L, 2272L, 2080L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L, 2016L, 2185L, 2320L, 2123L, 1824L, 2080L, 1952L, 2314L, 
    2272L, 2400L, 2144L, 2452L, 2128L, 2208L, 2395L, 2400L, 2272L, 
    2330L, 2576L, 2466L, 2656L, 2400L, 2848L, 2644L, 2464L, 2541L
    ), B08A = c(3232L, 2848L, 2976L, 2848L, 2976L, 2464L, 2208L, 
    2080L, 2256L, 2144L, 2016L, 2128L, 2455L, 2464L, 2336L, 1952L, 
    2272L, 2080L, 2540L, 2524L, 2592L, 2388L, 2604L, 2192L, 2588L, 
    2648L, 2699L, 2464L, 2656L, 2656L, 2833L, 2784L, 2720L, 2976L, 
    2953L, 2656L, 2902L), B12 = c(2400L, 2400L, 2400L, 2528L, 
    2496L, 2400L, 2336L, 1744L, 2144L, 2336L, 2224L, 2272L, 2336L, 
    2144L, 2144L, 1760L, 2096L, 1616L, 2592L, 2392L, 2528L, 2336L, 
    2576L, 1632L, 2448L, 2656L, 2845L, 1552L, 2512L, 1312L, 2947L, 
    1568L, 2842L, 1376L, 3087L, 1696L, 2784L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-37L))
```

I want perform time series analysis for all variables at once.
I am experiencing several difficulties. To begin with, the series must be turned into  `ts` object, but how it do for all variable at once.

```
mts <- ts(s, start = (ymd("2020-01-10")),
          frequency = 365.25 / 7)
```

But this is some kind of decimal series format, I need a regular one. `dd-mm-yyyy`
Now i see

```
Time Series:
Start = 18271 
End = 18271.6899383984 
Frequency = 52.1785714285714 
         date  red green blue  nir swir  B05  B06  B07 B08A  B12
18271.00    1 1600  1392  960 3096 3040 2016 2656 2976 3232 2400
18271.02    9 1360  1056  712 2696 3104 1696 2272 2528 2848 2400
```

For me, this format is not very convenient.

The second

```
fit <- auto.arima(mts)
Error in auto.arima(mts) : 
  auto.arima can only handle univariate time series
```

This is not surprising, because my series is multivariate, so I need perform for all the variables at once.

3 aspect is more theoretical:

```
frequency = 365.25 / 7
```

The fact is that I find it difficult to correctly set the frequency.

The fact is that the total data for six months, but they are not daily, but go in leaps, for example, 4 days after the last date, then 5, then 10, then 3, for example.
Therefore, please tell me how to correctly set the frequency parameter here?

And if I need to predict, for example, 5 dates ahead, but each step is 4 days
well, that is, for example, a forecast

```
14.03.2021
18.03.2021
22.03.2021
26.03.2021
30.03.2021
```

How can I correctly set the value when predicting?

```
forecast(fit, 5) #5?
```

5 dates but they are the same in 4 steps.

So the question is how do I:

1. Correctly get date format, not decimal?
2. How can I make `auto.arima` for all variables, after correctly specifying the frequency parameter for non-daily data?
3. And how to make a forecast for 5 dates ahead out of order?

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using the tsibble and fable packages, rather than the forecast package. It handles daily data better, with explicit dates, and allows many series to be forecast simultaneously. It includes the same algorithm as `forecast::auto.arima` for ARIMA models. Here is some code for your data set.

```r
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
my_ts <- as_tibble(s) |>
  mutate(
    date = stringr::str_replace_all(date, "\\.", "-"),
    date = dmy(date)
  ) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(red:B12, names_to = "series", values_to = "value") |>
  as_tsibble(index = date, key = series) |>
  fill_gaps()

my_ts |>
  model(arima = ARIMA(value)) |>
  forecast(h = 5)
#> # A fable: 50 x 5 [1D]
#> # Key:     series, .model [10]
#>    series .model date                value .mean
#>    <chr>  <chr>  <date>             <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 B05    arima  2021-03-15 N(1922, 20524) 1922.
#>  2 B05    arima  2021-03-16 N(1922, 41048) 1922.
#>  3 B05    arima  2021-03-17 N(1921, 61572) 1921.
#>  4 B05    arima  2021-03-18 N(1921, 82096) 1921.
#>  5 B05    arima  2021-03-19 N(1920, 1e+05) 1920.
#>  6 B06    arima  2021-03-15  N(2334, 3173) 2334.
#>  7 B06    arima  2021-03-16  N(2332, 6346) 2332.
#>  8 B06    arima  2021-03-17  N(2330, 9519) 2330.
#>  9 B06    arima  2021-03-18 N(2328, 12693) 2328.
#> 10 B06    arima  2021-03-19 N(2326, 15866) 2326.
#> # ℹ 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

More information about forecasting using these packages is available in my textbook at [OTexts.com/fpp3](https://OTexts.com/fpp3).